# How to generate 1000 unique color in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using force directed graph in which i have 1000 node. i want to display each node have different color. those node should be identifiable among other nodes.

I used the following d3 colors

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();
```

but the problem is it will generate only 20 colors after that again start using of same color for different group.

I have created 1000 unique color using following code using javascript:

```
   var color = [];
        for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
    /*      var randomcolor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
            color[i] = randomcolor;*/
    /*      var x=Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
            var y=(6-x.length);
            var z="000000";
            var z1 = z.substring(0,y);
            //var randcolor= "#" + z1 + x;
            var randcolor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFF0000<<0).toString(16);
            color[i] = randcolor;
   */       


        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var randcolor = '#';
        for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++ ) {
            randcolor += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
        }
        color[i]= randcolor;
    }
```

But the issue is so many color having same sades so those node are identifiable. how to generate color and each color should be unique from other same sades of colors.

Comment: A chart with a thousand nodes? Would anyone read that? [You have major UX issues on that](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/41172/10926). You might want to solve that rather than this problem.

Comment: I don't believe that there are 1000 different colours that are uniquely identifiable, certainly not by humans on a computer monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a related answer in case it helps someone:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25302128/9972273

There you have random color generator and can generate infinitely many colors. Below you've 1000.

```
"#3957ff", "#d3fe14", "#c9080a", "#fec7f8", "#0b7b3e", "#0bf0e9", "#c203c8", "#fd9b39", "#888593", "#906407", "#98ba7f", "#fe6794", "#10b0ff", "#ac7bff", "#fee7c0", "#964c63", "#1da49c", "#0ad811", "#bbd9fd", "#fe6cfe", "#297192", "#d1a09c", "#78579e", "#81ffad", "#739400", "#ca6949", "#d9bf01", "#646a58", "#d5097e", "#bb73a9", "#ccf6e9", "#9cb4b6", "#b6a7d4", "#9e8c62", "#6e83c8", "#01af64", "#a71afd", "#cfe589", "#d4ccd1", "#fd4109", "#bf8f0e", "#2f786e", "#4ed1a5", "#d8bb7d", "#a54509", "#6a9276", "#a4777a", "#fc12c9", "#606f15", "#3cc4d9", "#f31c4e", "#73616f", "#f097c6", "#fc8772", "#92a6fe", "#875b44", "#699ab3", "#94bc19", "#7d5bf0", "#d24dfe", "#c85b74", "#68ff57", "#b62347", "#994b91", "#646b8c", "#977ab4", "#d694fd", "#c4d5b5", "#fdc4bd", "#1cae05", "#7bd972", "#e9700a", "#d08f5d", "#8bb9e1", "#fde945", "#a29d98", "#1682fb", "#9ad9e0", "#d6cafe", "#8d8328", "#b091a7", "#647579", "#1f8d11", "#e7eafd", "#b9660b", "#a4a644", "#fec24c", "#b1168c", "#188cc1", "#7ab297", "#4468ae", "#c949a6", "#d48295", "#eb6dc2", "#d5b0cb", "#ff9ffb", "#fdb082", "#af4d44", "#a759c4", "#a9e03a", "#0d906b", "#9ee3bd", "#5b8846", "#0d8995", "#f25c58", "#70ae4f", "#847f74", "#9094bb", "#ffe2f1", "#a67149", "#936c8e", "#d04907", "#c3b8a6", "#cef8c4", "#7a9293", "#fda2ab", "#2ef6c5", "#807242", "#cb94cc", "#b6bdd0", "#b5c75d", "#fde189", "#b7ff80", "#fa2d8e", "#839a5f", "#28c2b5", "#e5e9e1", "#bc79d8", "#7ed8fe", "#9f20c3", "#4f7a5b", "#f511fd", "#09c959", "#bcd0ce", "#8685fd", "#98fcff", "#afbff9", "#6d69b4", "#5f99fd", "#aaa87e", "#b59dfb", "#5d809d", "#d9a742", "#ac5c86", "#9468d5", "#a4a2b2", "#b1376e", "#d43f3d", "#05a9d1", "#c38375", "#24b58e", "#6eabaf", "#66bf7f", "#92cbbb", "#ddb1ee", "#1be895", "#c7ecf9", "#a6baa6", "#8045cd", "#5f70f1", "#a9d796", "#ce62cb", "#0e954d", "#a97d2f", "#fcb8d3", "#9bfee3", "#4e8d84", "#fc6d3f", "#7b9fd4", "#8c6165", "#72805e", "#d53762", "#f00a1b", "#de5c97", "#8ea28b", "#fccd95", "#ba9c57", "#b79a82", "#7c5a82", "#7d7ca4", "#958ad6", "#cd8126", "#bdb0b7", "#10e0f8", "#dccc69", "#d6de0f", "#616d3d", "#985a25", "#30c7fd", "#0aeb65", "#e3cdb4", "#bd1bee", "#ad665d", "#d77070", "#8ea5b8", "#5b5ad0", "#76655e", "#598100", "#86757e", "#5ea068", "#a590b8", "#c1a707", "#85c0cd", "#e2cde9", "#dcd79c", "#d8a882", "#b256f9", "#b13323", "#519b3b", "#dd80de", "#f1884b", "#74b2fe", "#a0acd2", "#d199b0", "#f68392", "#8ccaa0", "#64d6cb", "#e0f86a", "#42707a", "#75671b", "#796e87", "#6d8075", "#9b8a8d", "#f04c71", "#61bd29", "#bcc18f", "#fecd0f", "#1e7ac9", "#927261", "#dc27cf", "#979605", "#ec9c88", "#8c48a3", "#676769", "#546e64", "#8f63a2", "#b35b2d", "#7b8ca2", "#b87188", "#4a9bda", "#eb7dab", "#f6a602", "#cab3fe", "#ddb8bb", "#107959", "#885973", "#5e858e", "#b15bad", "#e107a7", "#2f9dad", "#4b9e83", "#b992dc", "#6bb0cb", "#bdb363", "#ccd6e4", "#a3ee94", "#9ef718", "#fbe1d9", "#a428a5", "#93514c", "#487434", "#e8f1b6", "#d00938", "#fb50e1", "#fa85e1", "#7cd40a", "#f1ade1", "#b1485d", "#7f76d6", "#d186b3", "#90c25e", "#b8c813", "#a8c9de", "#7d30fe", "#815f2d", "#737f3b", "#c84486", "#946cfe", "#e55432", "#a88674", "#c17a47", "#b98b91", "#fc4bb3", "#da7f5f", "#df920b", "#b7bbba", "#99e6d9", "#a36170", "#c742d8", "#947f9d", "#a37d93", "#889072", "#9b924c", "#23b4bc", "#e6a25f", "#86df9c", "#a7da6c", "#3fee03", "#eec9d8", "#aafdcb", "#7b9139", "#92979c", "#72788a", "#994cff", "#c85956", "#7baa1a", "#de72fe", "#c7bad8", "#85ebfe", "#6e6089", "#9b4d31", "#297a1d", "#9052c0", "#5c75a5", "#698eba", "#d46222", "#6da095", "#b483bb", "#04d183", "#9bcdfe", "#2ffe8c", "#9d4279", "#c909aa", "#826cae", "#77787c", "#a96fb7", "#858f87", "#fd3b40", "#7fab7b", "#9e9edd", "#bba3be", "#f8b96c", "#7be553", "#c0e1ce", "#516e88", "#be0e5f", "#757c09", "#4b8d5f", "#38b448", "#df8780", "#ebb3a0", "#ced759", "#f0ed7c", "#e0eef1", "#0969d2", "#756446", "#488ea8", "#888450", "#61979c", "#a37ad6", "#b48a54", "#8193e5", "#dd6d89", "#8aa29d", "#c679fe", "#a4ac12", "#75bbb3", "#6ae2c1", "#c4fda7", "#606877", "#b2409d", "#5874c7", "#bf492c", "#4b88cd", "#e14ec0", "#b39da2", "#fb8300", "#d1b845", "#c2d083", "#c3caef", "#967500", "#c56399", "#ed5a05", "#aadff6", "#6685f4", "#1da16f", "#f28bff", "#c9c9bf", "#c7e2a9", "#5bfce4", "#e0e0bf", "#e8e2e8", "#ddf2d8", "#9108f8", "#932dd2", "#c03500", "#aa3fbc", "#547c79", "#9f6045", "#04897b", "#966f32", "#d83212", "#039f27", "#df4280", "#ef206e", "#0095f7", "#a5890d", "#9a8f7f", "#bc839e", "#88a23b", "#e55aed", "#51af9e", "#5eaf82", "#9e91fa", "#f76c79", "#99a869", "#d2957d", "#a2aca6", "#e3959e", "#adaefc", "#5bd14e", "#df9ceb", "#fe8fb1", "#87ca80", "#fc986d", "#2ad3d9", "#e8a8bb", "#a7c79c", "#a5c7cc", "#7befb7", "#b7e2e0", "#85f57b", "#f5d95b", "#dbdbff", "#fddcff", "#6e56bb", "#226fa8", "#5b659c", "#58a10f", "#e46c52", "#62abe2", "#c4aa77", "#b60e74", "#087983", "#a95703", "#2a6efb", "#427d92", "#78735c", "#c13c4b", "#437dae", "#9f5f95", "#51886f", "#74838a", "#8e7c5c", "#6e8f60", "#ae7764", "#e6409e", "#be7376", "#9790a8", "#da763c", "#d178c0", "#cf9641", "#66c466", "#94b0ec", "#9db6c6", "#72c2e4", "#70c3ff", "#94ce44", "#bcb8e8", "#73d1e5", "#accbb9", "#ddbb99", "#eeb91b", "#1efcaf", "#bef255", "#926b7c", "#fe6ab0", "#76e4e6", "#ebf219", "#5b4aff", "#bd61dc", "#9e969f", "#bda441", "#e18bcc", "#a9b0b8", "#fc81c6", "#eecc7d", "#eac6fc", "#fecfb3", "#5e7a4e", "#c3268c", "#8d6b48", "#3a8639", "#a66b09", "#877cbd", "#a579a4", "#e74654", "#b97901", "#d772a9", "#25bf83", "#8db15d", "#17bae3", "#e48e3a", "#5abea2", "#b0a892", "#d39e02", "#5cc2c5", "#caa3ed", "#d9a0c8", "#cda9b5", "#a9bfe3", "#ccc9dd", "#6fec8d", "#e9cdc9", "#b2ecb0", "#aa3a41", "#68716c", "#a43fd1", "#0b81a5", "#b34487", "#bc4f03", "#86719c", "#e00251", "#7a70fa", "#a76d8f", "#937b79", "#898687", "#e008ff", "#9388b5", "#709d4f", "#af8e3c", "#81a0a7", "#bc8c6d", "#fd563a", "#5ab166", "#93b391", "#91b5a8", "#b5b43c", "#c9a7d4", "#18d4b9", "#2ddb73", "#ccbdcc", "#e2bc5f", "#cac7a7", "#e5bde3", "#f8b4fc", "#d5d8d8", "#b9f5f4", "#ba1f2e", "#98557f", "#807002", "#825cd0", "#048953", "#b65076", "#7077b0", "#b35b64", "#aa672c", "#c040b9", "#6e81a7", "#249494", "#6a8d84", "#9e7e4b", "#6891d8", "#848bc6", "#d27010", "#a48acb", "#829ab9", "#8e97a9", "#76a285", "#98996c", "#fb7161", "#fd7a2c", "#c0a8a1", "#a7b762", "#b2aec8", "#a5ca79", "#aed8b2", "#cfe5fc", "#b2f1d7", "#6a6475", "#647761", "#358182", "#996abb", "#169987", "#3e99c2", "#ac928c", "#b68bf4", "#f1ac49", "#c1c6cd", "#1ce7ce", "#895391", "#4865db", "#45804c", "#597d2a", "#9c54a9", "#6c6bd3", "#83752e", "#9e52e2", "#b5569a", "#e31c34", "#848b12", "#ac6adc", "#948493", "#1aa34a", "#957be4", "#c664b1", "#dc596a", "#bf76c4", "#ab9927", "#be8cb4", "#a39bc8", "#e76cda", "#12c131", "#84aacb", "#c39a6b", "#84afbd", "#e38ead", "#84bb8b", "#6dce94", "#83cccc", "#fda4c4", "#30e5af", "#ffb1a8", "#b5d5e0", "#e2d037", "#38f1fd", "#beec77", "#9cf65e", "#e6e593", "#ebdff5", "#d9f892", "#6a5e9e", "#3d745f", "#4c7509", "#706c9c", "#83677e", "#be345f", "#695dfa", "#5c7987", "#797170", "#966459", "#d40c62", "#628564", "#b65c45", "#528b2c", "#b76e4c", "#e93d30", "#6f909f", "#7e9989", "#7f9a77", "#f615e0", "#53a5bc", "#f2528f", "#fd4a5e", "#9c9e83", "#bf9186", "#c786d3", "#2abd68", "#a3a3a7", "#8ab340", "#e48f6c", "#b2aeab", "#f4908c", "#b5b697", "#6fcbb6", "#14d1f5", "#e9a5a3", "#d5b0a1", "#f799df", "#c7bdbb", "#8ad5b5", "#f2b6bc", "#dcc99b", "#f4bd97", "#a8dcca", "#8beecd", "#d1dbcb", "#bfea08", "#e2d9d0", "#cfe3de", "#c7e8c4", "#e2e64f", "#acefff", "#5efdfb", "#f2e4a9", "#4a6b95", "#a1388c", "#6e51dc", "#a04a51", "#9a617d", "#d0533b", "#e8148f", "#7d8b4f", "#c16833", "#b8742c", "#a566fa", "#ad815e", "#c57561", "#919434", "#e25aad", "#3da2fd", "#ce70dd", "#e17d04", "#af9c6d", "#7eaca5", "#cc8d8e", "#cd83ec", "#b897bf", "#ada561", "#ae9cde", "#7fbb6f", "#c4a98b", "#acb47a", "#d2a55d", "#a5c141", "#92cee7", "#cdc47c", "#85e508", "#08fd6a", "#63fd10", "#feceeb", "#d5f4aa", "#5a61b2", "#88537f", "#556c76", "#4b6f6f", "#795f64", "#8c5560", "#805d55", "#566f4f", "#6f6838", "#a6422b", "#905806", "#b203cc", "#776d79", "#33816b", "#547a6b", "#71744d", "#c72d29", "#856c6d", "#3f79dc", "#c54962", "#d5324b", "#86778b", "#2c9436", "#6d881c", "#b24be3", "#9770a1", "#827c96", "#b5617a", "#c7592b", "#967b30", "#4b940b", "#7a8672", "#4e944f", "#e54702", "#4b8cf0", "#8588a5", "#7d8db4", "#848e98", "#4f9c91", "#c8688a", "#dd40e2", "#6c9f32", "#c3749c", "#1da890", "#c563fe", "#a888aa", "#4fa4a8", "#e66635", "#659fca", "#6ca3ef", "#11b3cc", "#a898af", "#93a57c", "#9aa0bd", "#95a4ab", "#ea7977", "#ff5acc", "#be97a5", "#f07d5a", "#64b6c4", "#6bbd92", "#fe6ce4", "#83c1a8", "#8fbfbf", "#c1b805", "#d8ae02", "#a9bcb6", "#eca27a", "#8ec0fe", "#bbb8c4", "#c9b78f", "#fc9e5c", "#a0cc02", "#c9b2e7", "#e3b178", "#c8c544", "#e4b7c9", "#73dead", "#b7d349", "#bbd19b", "#6feada", "#e6d5e2", "#eed7ad", "#e7d6fe", "#fcd6dc", "#73ffce", "#a8fbb3", "#9eff99", "#c9f8d7", "#f3ead6", "#a9307b", "#a3405f", "#34774d", "#8a40f0", "#7e6297", "#b815ad", "#c90a4c", "#856926", "#727223", "#825eb5", "#816c58", "#627694", "#39845f", "#cf3574", "#4f8bb4", "#468f9b", "#7b8483", "#8185da", "#dd5c51", "#a78485", "#de5a80", "#ff2e6a", "#bd8739", "#2fa8e2", "#929c93", "#8c9ad3", "#21b3aa", "#fe6616", "#fc4dfc", "#46b8f3", "#a3ad98", "#80c03e", "#a5b0c5", "#68d17e", "#aebdc5", "#99dc87", "#bccee6", "#ebc74d", "#b5e18b", "#dedd74", "#a44c73", "#6c7ad7", "#ec2f05", "#bd5bc6", "#549772", "#b57c87", "#ab7dc6", "#f823ae", "#929d51", "#73a966", "#61af32", "#d48543", "#43c808", "#fb7ca1", "#e49c3d", "#f69704", "#97c0a2", "#b3c27b", "#b9bfae", "#c5c062", "#48e246", "#d6c0b4", "#b7cdfe", "#d7c3ec", "#c7e24f", "#a0ebed", "#c9e0e6", "#ae390e", "#607435", "#943ce1", "#a809e8", "#6c6e78", "#8d5f8e", "#84698d", "#99653a", "#7f6ac3", "#c24944", "#577eba", "#698080", "#9f696a", "#cd03e8", "#a36e7e", "#3c9179", "#5a82da", "#987b86", "#ca5686", "#bf675b", "#de2fb7", "#cf51be", "#c97485", "#6ca1ae", "#7d9cfe", "#ec6c9c", "#e57fbe", "#b0a5b2", "#ca96df", "#abaee3", "#a5b992", "#e0a7e0", "#e2a7fe", "#0cdfd9", "#a2d1cc", "#8ad7ca", "#dabafd", "#eac0b1", "#9ce96c", "#fed46d", "#f1e106", "#96409b", "#5d6a6c", "#915533", "#8756a0", "#826170", "#6d6c64", "#a35123", "#0e7d93", "#6d6d83", "#9c5660", "#3f8000", "#4f61ff", "#097cb0", "#4c779a", "#a54d89", "#c12876", "#a45751", "#af4f2f", "#73776c", "#db0118", "#6c834f", "#0685df", "#8668df", "#028daa", "#a164a6", "#6a8193", "#4c7aff", "#d23699", "#93758a", "#d14856", "#c55c05", "#9172c2", "#b0659a", "#858367", "#a8753a", "#0c90d9", "#93816e", "#6d914b", "#c53cfe", "#668eaa", "#d05198", "#5d9481", "#c3666c", "#3a9d5f", "#f61236", "#b76bb2", "#9a884d", "#4ea456", "#45a634", "#b4841a", "#cf5ae2", "#a58895", "#92918e", "#869d02", "#b572f6", "#7e99ab", "#a285e5", "#e553d6", "#d867c1", "#33af78", "#a89275", "#b382df", "#5faa90", "#f06082", "#cf7e82", "#7ea695", "#8fa2ca", "#ca8d9f", "#e47c90", "#5cb5b3", "#07bea3", "#c099b5", "#96ad9b", "#a3a0fa", "#a0b33f", "#c496f7", "#07c99d", "#e7945b", "#83b9d2", "#0ad13c", "#7dc513", "#baabec", "#e992e4", "#18cfc7", "#b0b6d7", "#c2b1c6", "#ef9ab1", "#c2b87b", "#d1b361", "#82cd5b", "
```

Comment: Well, if they haven't figured it out by now... Besides--it's unlikely a purely random solution would work because (a) duplicates and (b) the possibility of generating essentially-identical colors is too high.

Comment: definitely, creating 1000 distinguishable colors is impossible, but it might help depending on the use case. I needed it for coloring clusters of points and it works like a charm. The only thing that mattered to me was that no two adjacent clusters had indistinguishable colors, which is highly probable given the above. Anyways, I am just trying to be helpful in case someone else stumbles on this post like I did