# Is there a way to generate more than 20 colors in D3?

Tags: d3.js

According to the [D3 Wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales). there is a scale function `d3.scale.category20()` that

> Constructs a new ordinal scale with a range of twenty categorical
>   colors:

Question: is there anything that one can do to generate more than 20 unique colors?  I was hoping to get at least 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the [source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/scale/category.js#L14-L42) for that method:

```
d3.scale.category20 = function() {
    return d3.scale.ordinal().range(d3_category20);
};
var d3_category20 = [
  0x1f77b4, 0xaec7e8,
  0xff7f0e, 0xffbb78,
  0x2ca02c, 0x98df8a,
  0xd62728, 0xff9896,
  0x9467bd, 0xc5b0d5,
  0x8c564b, 0xc49c94,
  0xe377c2, 0xf7b6d2,
  0x7f7f7f, 0xc7c7c7,
  0xbcbd22, 0xdbdb8d,
  0x17becf, 0x9edae5
].map(d3_rgbString);
```

You should be able to call `d3.scale.ordinal().range(...)` on your own color list.

Comment: so I have to create the color list

Comment: Yes.  Its just a list of hex values. `0x1f77b4` is the color `#1f 77 b4`

Comment: Expanded the above solution on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847161/how-can-i-generate-as-many-colors-as-i-want-using-d3/46305307#46305307)