# Apply a unique colour to each bar in d3.js V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying create a bar chart for top 10 among n number of entities. What I am trying to achieve is to give unique color to each bar. I am able to get the expected results when number of entities is 10 or less. [This is what I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4kx8.png)

I want to use colors from **d3.schemeCategory10** only. Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6vyBuR?p=info) code.

```
    bar_svg.selectAll("#bar_chart")
    .data(TOP_TEN_CHANNELS)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("rx", 2)         // set the x corner curve radius
    .attr("ry", 2)
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .style("fill", function(d,i){ return color(d.channel);})
    .attr("x", 35)
    .transition() 
    .ease(d3.easePoly)          // apply a transition
    .duration(500)
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth()-5)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.channel); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.views); });
```

Comment: That's what happens when you use a `for` loop in a D3 code...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I had the same concern but could not get find way to achieve as I am new to d3.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: I read your plunker too fast, just skimmed over it. Despite the `for` loop the problem here is different: you're passing an array of 20 values (that is, more than 10) to the scale which has only 10 colours in the range. The solution is passing your array of 10 top channels: https://plnkr.co/edit/rrAqlfRY21ZO6Wx2WsLO?p=preview. If you pass an array with more elements than the range the colours will repeat, that's the expected behaviour.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for reviewing my code. I had used the code and commented out that statement. What i need to do is randomize sequence of colors after every change in duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `schemeCategory10` to `schemeCategory20` in order to have 20 different colors. There are also other prebuilt color schemas using `schemeCategory20b` or `schemeCategory20c`.
Here is your code modified:

https://plnkr.co/edit/IsGQC75RIqoBijgcenu3

If you want even more colors you can follow the recipe I gave on another answer: [How can I generate as many colors as I want using d3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847161/how-can-i-generate-as-many-colors-as-i-want-using-d3/30912617#30912617)

Comment: Thnks @David. Currently I need only  10 colours.